# ImportError: No module named 'nested inline'

Tags: django

I´m using python 3.5.1 and django 2.0.1. I have a django app which I want to start but i get the following error message:
ImportError: No module named 'nested_inline'
Under settings.py I have in installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'nested_inline',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'betonermüdung'
]
```

So.. I can´t understand where the problem could be... can anyone help??
Thank you in advance

Comment: ImportError: No module named 'nested_inline'

in Application definnition there is:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
 'nested_inline',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',

 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'betonermüdung'
]

Comment: Did you install the `nested_inline` package?

Comment: Did you run `pip3 install django-nested-inline`?

Comment: Solved! I had to run the power shell as administrator to have the rights to install that package as you wrote. Thank you!

Comment: I think you better use a virtual environment to install packages. By giving admin right, you allow Python packages when installed to have access to your machine and make all sorts of changes. There have been reports of people registering "malware packages" that typically differ only *one* character from popular ones.